# How to send elements of the structure to switch

Tags: c, parsing

currently i am parsing the command line arguments in my C program, and I would like to learn from you, how to do it in the best way, below i have attached my source code, so this program processes the input looking like

WAE0500 /f1.txt /d; comment1 comment2

the result will be

- debug:1
- help:0
- file_used:1
- read:0
- write:1

When the flags are received, I would like to work only with two conditions: either WRITE or READ, 
so I would like to switch between the fields of this structure, the code below is wrong I know, but I hope it will help to understand my goal:

```
switch(Flags){
   case(flags.write):
    // do smth
     break;
   case(flags.write):
    // do smth
     break;
}
```

And here is my complete program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef enum { false, true } bool;

typedef struct   {
    bool debug;
    bool help;
    bool file_used;
    bool read;
    bool write;
}Flags;

void parse_input(Flags *flag, int argc, char *argv[], char *file_name);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Flags flag = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
    Flags *flag_ptr = &flag;

    char file_name[96];

    parse_input(&flag, argc, argv, file_name);


    return 0;
}
void parse_input(Flags *flag, int argc, char *argv[], char *file_name) {

    int i = 1; int j = 0;
    char cur_ch;
    while (i != argc) {

        cur_ch = argv[i][j];

        switch (cur_ch) {
        case 'W':
            flag->write = true;
            break;
        case'R':
            flag->read = true;
            break;
        case '/':
            j++;
            cur_ch = argv[i][j];
            switch (cur_ch) {
            case 'd':
                flag->debug = true;
                break;
            case 'f':
                flag->file_used = true;
                if (argv[i][j + 1] != ' ')
                    strcpy(file_name, &argv[i][j + 1]);
                break;
            case 'h':
                flag->help = true;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Bad Argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
            }

            break;
        case ';': // STOP WHILE
            i = argc - 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Bad Argument: %s\n", argv[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Such option can be a temporary solution, but I would like to learn how to do it correctly

```
char command_type = '\0';
if (flag.write)
    command_type = 'W';
else if(flag.read)
    command_type = 'R';
switch (command_type) {
    case 'W':
        //do smth
        break;
    case 'R':
        //do smth
        break;
}
```

UPD2:

```
enum FlagType { Read, Write, File_used, Debug, Help }; 

struct S { 
  FlagType type; 
  union { 
    // what to write in union?; 
  }; 
};
```

Comment: at `parse_input` You need reset `j` each loop.

Comment: Why `write:1` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I work with I2C interface, so I send either Write or Read commands, so and the command type depends on the first letter in the string "WAE0500", in this case it is write command, R0500 for ex. corresponds to Read, that's why the program checks only the first char and the second only in the case of flags (\d, \h)

Comment: `if (flag.write) {do smth} else if (flag.read) {do smth else}`

Comment: To begin with, check that the number of command line arguments match what you expect. And there is no reason to check argument 0, that's the name of the executable.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, good point about the argument 0,

Comment: @Lundin and considering the expected number of arguments, I have to consider all the possible variants, this app will be used by collegues

Comment: Firstly, you probably need to change second 'flags.write' (for command_type = 'R') with 'flags.read'. Secondly, yours is a classic case for using bit masks, instead of a boolean array.

Comment: @cyanide, could you please look at UPD2 and guide me? Thanks

Comment: I strongly recommend using POSIX [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) or GNU [`getopt()` or `getopt_long()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt)  — or any other option parsing library of your choice — rather than coding argument parsing _ad hoc_.  The ad hoc approach invariably leads to ad hoc results — some special case or another is overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

> Such option can be a temporary solution, but I would like to learn how to do it correctly
>
> ```
> char command_type = '\0';
> if (flag.write)
>     command_type = 'W';
> else if(flag.read)
>     command_type = 'R';
> switch (command_type) {
>     case 'W':
>         //do smth
>         break;
>     case 'R':
>         //do smth
>         break;
> }
> ```

Correct, or better said, sane would be to do it straightforwardly, just as n.m. suggested:

```
if (flag.write)
{
        //do smth
}
else
if (flag.read)
{
        //do smth
}
```

Using something like a `switch` with bit masks is just unnecessarily involved.